# OpenVINO + HDDL plugin - Cannot run openvino samples - "HDDL hardware initialization failed"

Tags: openvino, movidius

I'm trying to get OpenVINO samples working on an mPCIe Myriad X card (with 2 MA2485 chips).

My goal is to get the samples working using the HDDL plugin, as from my understanding it should allow for working with multiple chips in parallel.

Using the "MYRIAD" plugin, the benchmarks run successfully every single time:
`sudo -E ./demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.sh -d MYRIAD`

however, when switching to `-d HDDL` I get the following:

```
Run ./classification_sample -d HDDL -i /opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/demo/car.png -m /home/vino/openvino_models/ir/FP16//classification/squeezenet/1.1/caffe/squeezenet1.1.xml 

[ INFO ] InferenceEngine: 
    API version ............ 1.6
    Build .................. custom_releases/2019/R1.1_28dfbfdd28954c4dfd2f94403dd8dfc1f411038b
[ INFO ] Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Files were added: 1
[ INFO ]     /opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/demo/car.png
[ INFO ] Loading plugin

    API version ............ 1.6
    Build .................. 23780
    Description ....... HDDLPlugin
[ INFO ] Loading network files:
    /home/vino/openvino_models/ir/FP16//classification/squeezenet/1.1/caffe/squeezenet1.1.xml
    /home/vino/openvino_models/ir/FP16//classification/squeezenet/1.1/caffe/squeezenet1.1.bin
[ INFO ] Preparing input blobs
[ WARNING ] Image is resized from (787, 259) to (227, 227)
[ INFO ] Batch size is 1
[ INFO ] Preparing output blobs
[ INFO ] Loading model to the plugin
[16:52:27.5232][31126]I[ServiceStarter.cpp:93] Info: Found HDDL Service is not running. To start HDDL Service ...
[16:52:27.5241][31126]I[ServiceStarter.cpp:40] Info: Waiting for HDDL Service getting ready ...
Config file detected at /opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/config/bsl.json
scan F75114 device...
found 0 F75114 device
hid-f75114 init returned status BSL_ERROR_NO_HID_DEVICE_FOUND
ioexpander is disabled by config, skipping
mcu is disabled by config, skipping
Auto-scan is disabled by config, aborting
bsl init failed for:    BSL_ERROR_NO_HID_DEVICE_FOUND
[ion_close][69]close ion_fd = 3
Config file detected at /opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/config/bsl.json
scan F75114 device...
found 0 F75114 device
hid-f75114 init returned status BSL_ERROR_NO_HID_DEVICE_FOUND
ioexpander is disabled by config, skipping
mcu is disabled by config, skipping
Auto-scan is disabled by config, aborting
bsl init failed for:    BSL_ERROR_NO_HID_DEVICE_FOUND
## HDDL_INSTALL_DIR: /opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl
[16:52:27.5367][31131]I[ConfigParser.cpp:176] Config file '/opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/config/hddl_service.config' has been loaded
[16:52:27.5372][31131]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/var/tmp/hddl_service_alive.mutex owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5372][31131]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/var/tmp/hddl_service_ready.mutex owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5373][31131]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/var/tmp/hddl_start_exit.mutex owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5374][31131]I[AutobootStarter.cpp:150] Info: No running autoboot process. Start autoboot daemon...
Config file detected at /opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/config/bsl.json
scan F75114 device...
found 0 F75114 device
hid-f75114 init returned status BSL_ERROR_NO_HID_DEVICE_FOUND
ioexpander is disabled by config, skipping
mcu is disabled by config, skipping
Auto-scan is disabled by config, aborting
bsl init failed for:    BSL_ERROR_NO_HID_DEVICE_FOUND
[16:52:27.5457][31133]I[ConfigParser.cpp:176] Config file '/opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/config/hddl_autoboot.config' has been loaded
[16:52:27.5462][31133]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/var/tmp/hddl_autoboot_alive.mutex owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5463][31133]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/var/tmp/hddl_autoboot_ready.mutex owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5463][31133]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/var/tmp/hddl_autoboot_start_exit.mutex owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5463][31133]I[FileHelper.cpp:272] Set file:/tmp/hddl_autoboot_device.map owner: user-'no_change', group-'users', mode-'0660'
[16:52:27.5464][31133]I[AutoBoot.cpp:282] [Firmware Config] deviceName=default deviceNum=0 firmwarePath=/opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/lib/mvnc/MvNCAPI-ma2480.mvcmd
Reset all devices with device type 3
[16:52:27.5468][31133]ERROR[AutoBoot.cpp:444] Error: HDDL hardware initialization failed, exits now.
[ion_close][69]close ion_fd = 3
```

I've tried messing with various configuration options but to no avail.
I've also tried reinstalling Ubuntu, which did not work either.

Using Ubuntu 16.04.6, kernel 4.4.0-148-generic.

lshw entry:

```
       *-pci
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f7c00000-f7c07fff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@6
                   logical name: usb6
                   version: 4.04
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@5
                   logical name: usb5
                   version: 4.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb UNCLAIMED
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: Movidius MyriadX
                      vendor: Movidius Ltd.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@5:1
                      version: 0.01
                      serial: 03e72485
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

${HDDL_INSTALL_DIR}/config/bsl.json (tried multiple configurations here, nothing worked):

```
{
  "autoscan": false,
  "comment_on_autoscan": "auto-scan can be true or false",
  "hid-f75114": {
    "enabled": true,
    "Linux_comment": "You can use setup_tools/path_detaction.sh to get the suggested paths",
    "Linux_path_example": "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:04.0/0000:07:00.0/usb9/9-2/9-2.2/9-2.2:1.0",
    "Windows_comment": "HID\\VID_2C42&PID_5114\\6&A471F67&0&0000 is for Windows",
    "Comment": "Leave empty to pass all paths",
    "hid_paths": [
        "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0"
    ]
  },
  "ioexpander": {
    "enabled": false,
    "i2c_addr": [
      37,
      39
    ]
  },
  "mcu": {
    "enabled": false,
    "i2c_addr": [
      31
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a hardware issue.

Comment: I also had the same problem. What kind of hardware problem is it?

Comment: No idea - but our hardware supplier turned out to have a high defect rate. This disappeared when a replacement board was used instead